# how to overlay SVG Polyline points with z-index css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, svg

I am creating a 3D column chart with using VueJS and SVG, in which I have successfully implemented the chart but faced with difficulties to overlay group of polyline points that formed the columns over one another.

My 3D chart is here below

[image]

But I would like the columns to overlay as this sample chart does

[image]

I have set z-index by varying the index with counter on each series with hope that they will overlay on each other but i can't get it working.

This is my line of code

```
<g>
  <template v-for="(points,i) in barColumnPlot">
    <template v-for="(point,j) in points.series">
      <g style="stroke-width:1;" :stroke="point.stroke" :fill="point.stroke" fill-opacity="0.9" :style="'z-index:'+point.zIndex+';'">
        <polyline :points="point.front" />
        <polyline :points="point.right" />
        <polyline :points="point.top" />
      </g>
    </template>
  </template>
</g>
```

Please I need help.

Comment: This is a pen where you can see how to simulate the CSS z-index in SVG: [SVG z-index](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YXoEQe)

Comment: To achieve overlap you will need to make the bars completely opaque.

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta, i could understand from your example that the overlay happens by default in the order at which they are added to the DOM. so i reverse the array to add it in the order i would want them to overlay and it works now. Thanks guys